# Not able to update elements in arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, machine-learning

I have two matrices for feature and weight elements.I am implementing an learning algorithm. I want to update elements of arraylist(vector for representing one sample of feature). Following is the code. But my elements of matrices(vector elements are not) updated. I have put the sample solution too. same value before and after updating is not expected. Could you please let me know where is the flaw in code?

```
    for(int i =0 ; i< N ; i++){  //N is a large real number
    ArrayList<Double> featureVector = new ArrayList<Double>();
    featureVector = FeatureMatrix.get(i);
    System.out.println("Before::"+ featureVector);
    if(testList.contains(i)){
    for(int j=0 ; j< testList.size(); j++){
        if(i == testList.get(j)){       
        int indexInTestList= j;
        List<Double> subListNextCandidate ;
        subListNextCandidate =  weightVectorNextCandidate.subList((10*indexIntTestList),((10)*(indexInTestList+1))); //clips a portion of member from long list of members
        List<Double> approxWeight = new ArrayList<Double>();
        approxWeight = getApproxWeight(FeatureVector, indexInTestList, FeatureMatrix,WeightMatrix, bias); //approxWeight is a vector of same dimension as of featureVector

        for(int l=0 ; l< 10;l++){                 
            double Update = featureVector.get(l)+ Rate*((subListCandidate.get(l)-approxWeight.get(l))-(lambda*featureVector.get(l)*(1/M)));//M is large real number
            featureVector.set(l,Update);

        }                   
        }
    }
    }

    else{
    for(int l=0 ; l< 10;l++){
        double Update = featureVector.get(l)  -Rate*(lambda*featureVector.get(l)*(1/M));
        featureVector.set(l, Update);
    }                   
    }
    System.out.println("After:::"+ FeatureMatrix.get(i) );  
}
```

Sample output is::

```
 Before::[0.04539928251182193, -0.16233604402485394, 0.905018369795912, -1.2817141994528614, 0.7065420460225843, -0.8946090188977665, -1.74892020689701, -2.1539901172158187, 1.8229765478806985, -1.8109945435256574]
 After:::[0.04539928251182193, -0.16233604402485394, 0.905018369795912, -1.2817141994528614, 0.7065420460225843, -0.8946090188977665, -1.74892020689701, -2.1539901172158187, 1.8229765478806985, -1.8109945435256574]
```

Comment: You should use debugger and step through the lines in your code.

Comment: 1. format your code 2. where the `testList` is coming from ? (no initialization in the code you posted.)

Comment: test list comes as parameter of the method.

Answer (score 2):

I can think of only a couple of reasonable reasons why this would happen:

1. Rate == 0
2. testList.contains(i) is always false

I would strongly suggest using breakpoints to debug this. At the very least, put a System.out.println where featureVector.set() is called to make sure it is ever called. I'm guessing it's never called because the conditions never become true.

Do use breakpoints, it'll be a life saver...

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of `testList.get(j)`?  You're comparing an integer to what I suspect is a double.  That's not very likely to go well ...